# get errors when using "set_edge_attributes"

Tags: python, networkx

When I try to use set_edge_attributes in networkx to assign an integer value to a new attribute for all the edeges(have an undirected networkx G already):

```
 nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 'new_attr', 1)
```

The error shows

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'

But since by https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html :

> If values is not a dictionary, then it is treated as a single attribute value that is then applied to every edge in G.

So it should be OK to set the same integer value for every edges in the graph? Or I can't 'create' a new attribute and have to use an existing attribute?

Update:
It seems that I can use

```
 G.edge[u][v]['new_attr']
```

to create and access an attribute. But is there an easier way to assign the value at once without using a loop? I need to initialize the network with the same initial value for the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the right idea. For example

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.path_graph(4)

In [3]: nx.set_edge_attributes(G,'foo',1)

In [4]: list(G.edges(data=True))
Out[4]: [(0, 1, {'foo': 1}), (1, 2, {'foo': 1}), (2, 3, {'foo': 1})]
```

Perhaps your graph G is corrupted?  Post a complete example if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. I don't know why it didn't work yesterday.

Comment: Btw, I realized that in my other computer which has python version 2.7.3 this error message still pops up. In such case do I need to update my python first?

Comment: Note that the call order of arguments `values` and `name` switched between v1.x & v2.x. [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html?highlight=set_edge_attributes#networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes)